# Project generated with cmake for Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I followed [How to configure a C/C++ project with Eclipse and CMake](http://sgpsproject.sourceforge.net/JavierVGomez/index.php/How_to_configure_a_C/C++_project_with_Eclipse_and_CMake) article to import my project which was generated with cmake to Eclipse CDT. All went fine except when debugging.

I get this error  when trying to debug

```
No source available for "main() at 0x5bca71"
```

And in gdb console window, here's the message

```
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
No source file named /home/.../Desktop/GP/Test/src/Main.cpp.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
```

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and cmake version 2.8.10.1 in Linux Mint 15

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324602/no-source-available-for-main-error-when-debugging-simple-c-in-eclipse-with

Comment: I already visited that question, and all others I found the whole day but it didn't fixed my problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453851/how-to-configure-eclipse-cdt-for-cmake

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug` and regenerating/rebuilding project.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day of struggling, I switch to Kdevelop4. Importing a cmake project is just as simple as opening the CMakeList.txt file and Kdevelop will do the rest for you. It is so fast, especially its code completion.